# Borgakh the Steel Heart not following after marriage

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I can't make Borgakh follow me anymore after marriage, is this normal or is this some kind of bug? It's pretty annoying! If this is a bug, could you please tell me how to fix it? I want to have her as a companion! D:

Answer (score -1):

Yes they can, but only if they were followers to begin with.